# xamarin forms HttpClient call in a loop

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i am new to Xamairin form development, i have list of items value and i want to fetch subitems collections in order to items id , so i looped items and inside the  loop just call HttpClient get request  to fetch subitems and doing some add to another list to display listview with header template, the issue is when i call httpclient inside loop 1st time it fetch the data and the next time it has thorwn System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request
can you any one help me, how od i overcome this

11-06 16:44:32.517 I/MonoDroid(13270): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270): System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x0041d] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.522 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at Expertential.Services.ActivityTaskListViewModelService+<GetActivityList>d__9.MoveNext () [0x0012b] in E:\RNSTFS\Expertential Mobile\Expertential.Mobile\Expertential\Expertential\Services\ActivityTaskListViewModelService.cs:66 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at Expertential.ViewModels.DashBoardViewModel+d__74.MoveNext () [0x000df] in E:\RNSTFS\Expertential Mobile\Expertential.Mobile\Expertential\Expertential\ViewModels\DashBoardViewModel.cs:325 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 () [0x00000] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
11-06 16:44:32.523 I/MonoDroid(13270):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.91b49edf-9891-4d0a-b0ee-998e603a63ec(intptr,intptr)
11-06 16:44:32.537 W/art     (13270): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable
11-06 16:44:32.542 D/Mono    (13270): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
11-06 16:44:32.542 D/Mono    (13270): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
11-06 16:44:32.542 D/Mono    (13270): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
11-06 16:44:32.542 D/Mono    (13270): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.

here is my code  ViewModel class

```
   public async void GetToday(DateTime filterdate, ObservableCollection<TodaysActivity> TodaysActivityList)
        {
            var count = 0;
            ObservableCollection<TodaysProjectList> ne = new ObservableCollection<TodaysProjectList>();
            activityTaskListViewModelService = new ActivityTaskListViewModelService();

           foreach(TodaysActivity act in TodaysActivityList)
            {
                count = count + 1;
                TodaysProjectList t = new TodaysProjectList()
                {
                    clientName = act.clientName,
                    projectNick = act.projectNick,

                    DashboardActivitys = await activityTaskListViewModelService.GetActivityList(filterdate, act.projectId)
                };
                ne.Add(t);
               // return;
            }
            Todays = todays;

        }
```

Service class

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<DashboardActivity>> GetActivityList(DateTime filterDate, int projectId)
        {
            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                ObservableCollection<DashboardActivity> activityList = new ObservableCollection<DashboardActivity>();
                string token = "";
                if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("TOKEN_AUTH"))
                {
                    token = Application.Current.Properties["TOKEN_AUTH"].ToString();
                }
                _client = new HttpClient();
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                getUrlActivity = constDomain + getUrlActivity;
                var response = await _client.GetAsync(getUrlActivity + filterDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "&projectId=" + projectId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(true); //projectId=8113&activityId=817411
                _client.Dispose();



                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic attachment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
                    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DashboardActivity>>(str);
                    activityList = new ObservableCollection<DashboardActivity>(model);

                    for(int i=0;i<activityList.Count;i++)
                    {
                        var innerObj = attachment[i].attachments;
                        var obj = innerObj.ToObject<List<Attachments>>();
                        activityList[i].attachements = obj;
                    }

                    return activityList;
                }
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I would start by not creating a new HttpClient object for each call

Comment: i removed the object of HttpClient , but still same error occuring

Comment: NameResolutionFailure is usually a DNS error - it's weird you would only get that on subsequent calls

Comment: Looks like the issue is there because of this line in your service class :
                getUrlActivity = constDomain + getUrlActivity;
Can you debug and see what URL is being created! Looks like getUrlActivity is in Class level access and which is being concatenated !

Comment: var URL creation works fine , i debugged, even first time it calls & fetch data but the problem is second time call the request it throws exception